# Compact way to extract parts of strings (FASTA header)

Tags: c++, string, sequence

Given the following string:

```
string Header =">day11:1:356617";
```

How do you extract everything except ">",
yielding only:

```
day11:1:356617
```

I could do standard loop over the string character
and keep only other than ">".

```
string nStr ="";
for (int i=0; i < Header.size(); i++) {
    if (Header[i] != ">") {
       nStr = nStr + Header[i];
     }
}
```

But the approach seems
too clumsy and slow, in particular I need to do such
extraction for millions of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (Header[0] == '>') Header = Header.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

...You didn't say ***anything*** about the "domain" of the inbound strings or what you're looking to chomp. If it's just strings of the form you gave, this would be the fastest:

```
Header.substring(1);
```

Comment: This is C++, std::string has no substring() method.